# How to skip a value from a sum in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

If my value is -99999999999999, I need to skip it from a sum. Is that possbile?

```
"aggs": {
    "group_by_PriceSavings": {
        "sum": {
            "field": "PriceSavings"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a query part that ignores documents with that value:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "PriceSavings": {
        "gt": -99999999999999
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_PriceSavings": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "PriceSavings"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the aggs? maybe with a filter?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html), however it's usually more optimal to do it in the query part.